# Prevent Thunderbird from automatically marking messages as read on the server when just downloaded?

Tags: thunderbird

Thunderbird marks ALL downloaded messages as read on a server, even if I didn't open any of them. E.g. my android mail client doesn't have such problem - message marked as read on a server only when I actually open this particular message.

So if Thunderbird is running in background on my desktop, it keeps marking all incoming mail messages as read automatically. It's annoying, sometimes I miss important messages when checking mail from android, because everything is marked as read.

Comment: are you using `pop` protocol?

Comment: Yes, I was using `POP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have configured your mailclient as POP3 rather than IMAP.

This is how POP3 works. In order to fix this, Backup the email on your computer, then remove the account and reconfigure as IMAP.